# Filter list using foldr in Scheme

Tags: scheme, fold

I am trying to filter a list using "foldr" in Scheme, and leave the list only with the elements that return "true" for some given predicate.
I tried to use the previous discussings here regarding foldr/l in scheme (e.g, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780472/reverse-a-list-in-scheme-with-foldl-and-foldr)), and came out with this code:

```
(define (filterb pred? lst)
 (foldr (lambda (e a)
       (if (pred? e)
           (cons e a)
           a))
     lst
     '()))
```

The running command is for example:

> (filterb even? '(1 2 3 4))

but unfortunately, it always return the given list.

I would be happy to get some help as for what am I doing wrong and why is the filtering not taking place.
Thanks!

Comment: `foldr` usually doesn't take its arguments in that order. Check your documentation.

Comment: Thanks! That's it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldr%29%29), `foldr` usually takes as parameters a procedure, an initial value and an input list *in that order*. Your code is mostly right, except that the last two arguments passed to `foldr` are inverted. As mentioned in the comments, you simply have to reverse the order:

```
(define (filterb pred? lst)
  (foldr (lambda (e a)
           (if (pred? e)
               (cons e a)
               a))
         '()
         lst))
```

It works as expected:

```
(filterb even? '(1 2 3 4))
=> '(2 4)
```