# Where's foldl1 and foldr1 in Racket?

Tags: racket, fold

Racket has only [`foldl`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29) and [`foldr`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldr%29%29), which require initial value. Haskell in addition has [`foldl1`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3afoldl1) and [`foldr1`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3afoldr1), which instead of applying a function on the initial value and the first element, applies to first and second element. Currently i implemented them as:

```
(define (foldl1 f xs)
  (foldl f (first xs) (rest xs)))
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: No, I don't know a better way. By the way, although you probably already know this, [`foldl` is not exactly the same in Racket and Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778492/why-is-foldl-defined-in-a-strange-way-in-racket?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way, just `(require srfi/1)` and use `reduce` and `reduce-right`. :-D

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing looks like `reduce` in CL. Your procedure looks ok except it would fail if the list is empty.

Be aware that `first` and `rest` are not the same as `car` and `cdr` since they only work on proper lists. eg.

```
(first '(a b c d e . f))
;;==> 
;;first: contract violation
;;  expected: (and/c list? (not/c empty?))
;;  given: '(a b c d e . f)
```

Now. For racket to signal here it must have traversed the whole list to make sure it ends with null and since it didn't it signaled an error. I did a small test and found out that sorting a 2 million list used 32% more time with `first`/`rest`.