# How to filter a list using foldl

Tags: scheme, fold

I try to get the positive integers in Scheme but must use foldl

so... here is foldl code

```
foldl implementation
(define foldl
 (lambda (proc acc lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      acc
      (foldl proc
           (proc acc (car lst))
           (cdr lst)))))
```

then my code 
it should take positive integers using fold: foldl-positive-integer . I know it is wrong, I just start to learn scheme.
here have to check 1) is integer? 2) is positive? 3) output should be the multiplication of all the positive e.g. input '(1 2 3 6 0 -5 "scheme") => output should be: 36

**[Q1] how to implement nested-if like if(real?) if(integer?) ..... inside foldl or any other way using foldl?**

```
(define (foldl-positive-integer)
  (foldl
    (lambda (x y) (if (real? x) (* x y) x))
    '()
    lst
))
```

**[Q2] my code returns empty list all the time? why?**

Comment: The product of 1, 2, 3, 6 is not 12, it's 36.

Comment: right, I was mixed up with other practice (even numbers).. it is not only even numbers.. it's the multiplication of all numbers (integers) together..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About Q1: You have to somehow skip over the elements in the list which are not positive numbers. One idea is to first [`filter`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29) them out, as Chris shows. An alternative would be to filter them out with `foldl` itself:

```
(define (product-of-positives lst)             ; pass input list as parameter
  (foldl (lambda (acc e)                       ; acc goes first in your foldl
           (if (and (number? e) (positive? e)) ; if it's a positive number
               (* e acc)                       ; then multiply it
               acc))                           ; otherwise keep same acc
         1                                     ; multiplicative identity
         lst))                                 ; input list
```

Now, for Q2: your implementation isn't right. For starters, you are not even passing a list as parameter - the `list` at the end is a built-in procedure, and you should not name a variable like that to avoid this kind of confusions - better use `lst`, for instance.

Let's say you fix that and pass along a list parameter - then you'll find out that the `acc` parameter isn't right, if you want to multiply a list then it must be `1`, because we're building a *number* as the output (not a list), and it can't be `0` because it will cancel out all the values - we're multiplying them after all.

One last thing - using just `real?` won't work for picking the *positive* numbers in the list. Better stick with either of the implementations we've shown:

```
(product-of-positives '(1 2 3 6 0 -5 "scheme"))
=> 36
```

Comment: It works. I like the comments next the code. Really helpful. Thx.
 Curiosity: another question - when your/or someone else's code was (the first one, before removed or modified). 
It was like this (foldl (lambda e acc).. in line 2  I've got "scheme" from (product-of-positives '(1 2 3 6 0 -5 "scheme")) and "-5" from (product-of-positives '(1 2 3 6 0 -5)) but if I give only positives (product-of-positives '(1 2 3 6)) then it's output right 36. when is like this (foldl (lambda e acc).. in line 2.. what happens?

Comment: That's because you changed the order of the parameters in the function  passed along to `foldl`, and you end up returning the `acc` part of the conditional for the last element, which happens to be `"scheme"`. See the discussion we had about that in your previous question, and also see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778492/). As I said before, I prefer to use the order `(e acc)` in `foldl`.

Comment: I appreciate the answer/and I've got much better understanding from your answer , however, I just saw this question received -2 (no research effort...) I don't know how the votes are working.. but I feel I should delete this question. maybe they think it is not appropriate. but I really appreciate your answer for this.

Comment: @user1915570 I disagree with the downvotes, let's leave it at 0 points - not a stellar question, but not terrible bad either.

Comment: Let's do that. The answers you provided, I also look at it again to remind myself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you included your `fold` since it's not consistent if the accumulator is going as the first or last argument. Now I've just loaded your code in DrRacket and renamed the variables so that I can clearly see the accumulator. The error is clear:

```
(define (foldl-positive-integer)
  (foldl
    (lambda (acc element) 
      (if (real? acc)      ; never real? since it's a list
          (* acc element)
          acc))
    '()                    ; acc should be the default return, perhaps 1.0?
    list))                 ; NB! using list as a variable overshadows list the procedure
```

A2: So for each element `()` is not `real?` so the empty list is the return for every iteration.

Now. If the result should be a `real?` then the initial accumulator needs to be `real?` as well. Perhaps `1.0`. Then the tests should be done on the new element and not the accumulator which we know is `real?` I think a working version would be something like this:

```
(foldl
 (lambda (acc element) 
   (if (real? element) ; fixed from accumulator to element
       (* acc element) ; multiply if real?
       acc))           ; else just continue using the previous acc
 1.0                   ; initial accumulator
 list)
```

As for A1: The joining procedure can be anything using any logic. The only thing is that the previous iteration (or initial value) is the first argument and the element to process is the second. You can do this:

```
(define (fold-join acc e)
  (cond ((list? e) (+ acc (length e)))              ; for lists add the length
        ((and (integer? e) (negative? e) (- acc e))); negative integers, abs 
        ((integer? e) (+ acc e))                    ; positive integers
        (else acc)))                                ; ignore everything else 

(foldl fold-join 0 '((1 2 3) -5 5 2.3 9.8)) ; ==> 13
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer/and I've got much better understanding from your answer , however, I just saw this question received -2 (no research effort...) I don't know how the votes are working.. but I feel I should delete this question. maybe they think it is not appropriate. but I really appreciate your answer for this.

Comment: @user1915570 The downvotes are indicators, close votes are the communities way of cleaning up and you as OP can choose to delete your post. I don't mind and I'm sure Chris and Oscar don't mind either if you choose to delete it and its your right. If you choose to keep it consider editing it so that it's easier to find for others. Eg. change the title to "How to filter a list using foldl".

Comment: Yes. Let's try. The answers you provided, I also look at it again to remind myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (product-of-positives lst)
  (foldl * 1 (filter (lambda (x)
                       (and (number? x) (positive? x)))
                     lst)))
```

Comment: I try not to use operators.. Because I just start to learn Scheme. So try to do things without easy ( or even smart) way until I get used to it. Thx

Comment: That's fine, but eventually you'll get to a place where you'll want to use the "pro" method, and then you can come back to this answer. :-)