# Foldr and Foldl in DrRacket

Tags: scheme, racket

I can see how it does it on

```
(foldl * 1 '(1 2 3 4 5)) == 120
(foldr * 1 '(1 2 3 4 5)) == 120
```

but I can't figure out how it gets 2 for
     (foldl - 1 '(1 2 3 4 5)) == 2

I would've thought (foldl - 1 '(1 2 3 4 5)) would be ((((1-1)-2)-3)-4)-5), a negative number. What did I miss?

I can tho see why 
    (foldl + 1 '(1 2 3 4 5)) == 16

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778492/why-is-foldl-defined-in-a-strange-way-in-racket) and its answers for why this is. There are arguments for both ways of defining `foldl`, but this one was chosen for Racket because the accumulator-last version is more consistent with `foldr`, because then both of them take functions that take the accumulator as the last argument.

Comment: Also know that Scheme (like the Standard, AKA R6RS for now) has a library with the procedures `fold-right` and `fold-left` where the placement of the accumulator changes. I seldom use those as [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html) has lots of support and use the same accumulator placement for `fold` and `fold-right`, even from [`#!racket`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-1.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(foldl - 1 '(1 2 3 4 5))` is actually equivalent to `(- 5 (- 4 (- 3 (- 2 (- 1 1)))))`, or, in infix, `5 - (4 - (3 - (2 - (1 - 1))))`.

Likewise, `(foldr - 1 '(1 2 3 4 5))` is actually equivalent to `(- 1 (- 2 (- 3 (- 4 (- 5 1)))))`, or, in infix, `1 - (2 - (3 - (4 - (5 - 1))))`.