# Understanding the primitive "foldl" in Racket

Tags: lisp, racket, fold

I am a beginner and I am trying to understand the primitive function foldl/foldr. I read the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html) and tried some things.
However, I just cannot grasp its behavior in this case:

```
(foldl expt 2 '(1 2 3 4))
>> 262144
```

I think the result should be the same as:

```
(expt (expt (expt (expt 2 1) 2) 3) 4)
>> 16777216
```

I can't trace foldl since the function is a primitive. I do not see how the procedure achieves this result. I am using Racket and Dr. Racket.

Comment: This post may also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018163/expanded-form-of-fold-in-racket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding of `foldl` has the argument order backwards (though that’s understandable, since the argument order of fold/reduce tends to [vary somewhat arbitrarily between languages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8780880/465378)). The correct equivalency is as follows:

```
> (foldl expt 2 '(1 2 3 4))
262144
> (expt 4 (expt 3 (expt 2 (expt 1 2))))
262144
```

As a small aside, `foldl` *is* built-in to `#lang racket/base`, but it’s *not* a primitive in the sense that it is implemented in the runtime. If you are using DrRacket, you can right-click on a use of `foldl` and select “Open Defining File” to open the module where it’s implemented, which is `racket/private/list` in this case.