# Sum items in list Racket

Tags: racket

I'm working with simple lists in Racket, and I was doing a function to sum the elements of a list.

But I would like to know if there is any simpler way to do this.

I did this **function**:

```
(define (mySum L)
  (if (empty? L) 0
      (+ (first L) (mySum (rest L))))
  )
```

**output:**

```
(mySum '(1 2 3 4))
10
```

I wanted to know if anyone knows a simpler way to do this. I explain myself, for example:
This is another **function** I did:

```
(define (myAppend L1 L2)
  (if (empty? L1) L2
      (cons (car L1) (myAppend (cdr L1) L2)))
  )
```

But this function can be done more simply by doing just this:

```
(define (myAppend L1 L2)
  (append L1 L2)
  )
```

My **problem** is to know if there is a simpler way to do the sum of items in a list. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you're going for is a short program,

```
(define (mySum L)
  (apply + L))
```

is shorter. Whether it is "simpler" is a matter of interpretation: The way you've written it seems "simpler" in that it is defined purely based on the structure of lists, whereas `(apply + L)` relies on both a semi-magical function (`apply`) and a semi-fancy behavior of `+` (the fact that it takes a variable number of arguments) that itself has to do something similar to what you've already written.

(Incidentally, I wouldn't call your `myAppend` example simpler, either -- the first one actually *defines* the function you want, whereas the second just *refers* to the behavior you want, which in turn had to be defined elsewhere. If you're doing this as part of a practical program, `(apply + L)` and using the built-in `append` are certainly the way to go, but if this is for educational purposes then I think the initial versions of both functions are superior.)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 4):

Another way to approach it would be

```
(define (my-sum lst)
 (foldr + 0 lst))
```

This uses built-in function foldr and is fairly short. Foldr consumes a function (+), base-case (0) and a list (lst). I've attached a link to a visual representation of foldr, as well as a link that explains it really well.

[image: link]

More information [here](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/foldr_f.html)

Comment: Some interesting discussion on fold here also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018163/expanded-form-of-fold-in-racket.

Answer (score 2):

```
(apply + '(elements_of_list))
```

:)

Comment: Would be better if you explained why and how this code solves the problem. Formatting the code is also nice. Is that `:)` part of the code?

Answer (score 1):

One can also use `for/sum`:

```
(define (my+ L)
  (for/sum ((i L))
    i))

(my+ '(1 2 3 4))  ; => 10
```

'named let' is a version similar to recursive functions but may be easier to understand:

```
(define (myplus L)
  (let loop ((L L)
             (s 0))
    (cond
      [(empty? L) s]
      [else (loop (rest L) 
                  (+ s (first L)))] )))
```

'cond' can also be replaced by 'if' here, since there are only 2 cases. The keyword 'else' can also be omitted.