# How do foldl and foldr work, broken down in an example?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, fold

Okay, I am new with scheme/racket/lisp. I am practicing creating my own functions, syntax, and recursion, so I want to make my own `foldl` and `foldr` functions that do exactly what the predefined versions do. I can't do it because I just don't understand how these functions work. I have seen similar questions on here but I still don't get it. Some examples broken down would help! Here is my (incorrect) process:

`(foldl - 0 '(1 2 3 4))` I do `0 -(4-3-2-1)` and get 2 which is the right answer

`(foldl - 0 '(4 3 2 1))` I do `0-(1-2-3-4)` and get 8 but it should be -2.

`(foldr - 0 '(1 2 3 4))` I do `0-(1-2-3-4)` and get 8 again, but it should be -2.

`(foldr - 0 '(4 3 2 1))` I do `0-(4-3-2-1)` and get 2 which is the right answer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may find discussion on this page also useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018163/expanded-form-of-fold-in-racket

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Let's look at: `(foldr - 0 '(1 2 3 4))`.

Here the literal `'(1 2 3 4)` constructs a list whose elements are the numbers 1, 2, 3, and, 4. Let's make the construction of the list explicit:

```
(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 empty))))
```

One can think of `foldr` as a function that replaces `cons` with a function `f` and empty with a value `v`.

Therefore

```
(foldr f 0 (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 empty)))))
```

becomes

```
           (f 1    (f 2    (f 3    (f 4 v)))))
```

If the function f is `-` and the value `v` is 0, you will get:

```
(- 1 (- 2 (- 3 (- 4 0)))))
```

And we can calculate the result:

```
  (- 1 (- 2 (- 3 (- 4 0))))
= (- 1 (- 2 (- 3 4)))
= (- 1 (- 2 -1))
= (- 1 3)
= -2
```

Note that `(foldr cons empty a-list)` produces a copy of `a-list`.

The function `foldl` on the other hand uses the values from the other side:

```
> (foldl cons empty '(1 2 3 4))
'(4 3 2 1)
```

In other words:

```
(foldl f v '(1 2 3 4))
```

becomes

```
(f 4 (f 3 (f 2 (f 1 v)))).
```

If `f` is the function `-` and the value is 0, then we get:

```
  (- 4 (- 3 (- 2 (- 1 0))))
= (- 4 (- 3 (- 2 1)))
= (- 4 (- 3 1))
= (- 4 2)
= 2
```

Note that `(foldl cons empty a-list)` produces the reverse of `a-list`.

Comment: Note that `(- 1 3) = -2`, so `(foldr - 0 '(1 2 3 4))` should evaluate to -2 and not 2. Same with `foldl`, it should be 2 and not -2. `(foldl f v '(1 2 3 4))` should become `(f 4 (f 3 (f 2 (f 1 v))))`.

Comment: @AlexanderMaru Thanks! I have fixed the mistakes.

Comment: @soegaard really cool demonstration of `foldl`; I've never seen it using the expanded `cons` form like you've done here <3

Comment: Love this kind of examples. Thank you!

Comment: This is the best and most simplest explanation to foldr. I've researched this topic for a while now and i couldn't figure it out what foldr is doing. Your explanation is so on point! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can illustrate what is going on in `fold`, if you create a procedure, which does the same like `cons` but reverses the arguments. I have called it `snoc` in the following example.

```lisp
(define fldl
  (lambda (proc a lst)
    (if (pair? lst)
      (fldl proc
            (proc (car lst)
                  a)
            (cdr lst))
      a)))

(define fldr
  (lambda (proc a lst)
    (if (pair? lst)
      (proc (car lst)
            (fldr proc
                  a
                  (cdr lst)))
      a)))

(define lst (list 1 2 3 4))

(fldl + 0 lst)      ;; => 10
(fldl * 1 lst)      ;; => 24
(fldl cons '() lst) ;; => (4 3 2 1)

(fldr + 0 lst)      ;; => 10
(fldr * 1 lst)      ;; => 24
(fldr cons '() lst) ;; => (1 2 3 4)

(define snoc (lambda (a b) (cons b a)))

(fldl snoc '() lst) ;; => ((((() . 1) . 2) . 3) . 4)
(fldr snoc '() lst) ;; => ((((() . 4) . 3) . 2) . 1)
```